# Create a zip file and download all files using paperclip Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to download `n` number of images uploaded using paperclip as a zip.

```
def download
  require 'zip'
  @files = Upload.where(:request_id => params[:id])
  t = Tempfile.new('tmp-zip-' + request.remote_ip)
  Zip::OutputStream.open(t.path) do |zos|
    @files.each do |file|
      puts file.image.url(:original, false)
      zos.add(file.image, file.image.url(:original, false))
      zos.put_next_entry(file.image)
    end
  end
end
```

I am getting this error

> undefined method 'add' for `#<Zip::OutputStream:0x007f39508516d8>`

Comment: Maybe use `ZipFile` instead of `OutputStream`?